# In python, how to call a function C nested under another function B inside a class A from outside of the class

Tags: python, oop, nested-function

In python, how to call a function C nested under another function B inside a class A from outside of the class.

```
>>> class A:
...    def funcB(self):
...       print('inside funcB')
...       def funcC(self):
...          print('hello world')
...
>>> a=A()
>>> c=a.funcB()
inside funcB
>>> c=a.funcB.funcC()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'funcC'
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. You also apparently don't have a function called `funC` because you named it `funcC`

Comment: Make it a staticmethod?

Comment: You don't, because it only exists during an invocation of `A.funcB()`.

Answer (score 1):

This is just like asking how can I read the value of a variable defined inside a function, from outside the function.

You can't. The inner variable only exists when the function is called; and once the function returns, the inner variable is discarded.

It works the same for anything defined within a function; a string, a function, a variable, etc.

The only way to "call it" would be to return it from the function.